Determining convergence and evaluating a limit of an integral
Show the following limit converges and find its value:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_0^{1/x}\frac{u^2}{{(e^u-e^{-u})}^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2u^2}}du.$$
Plugging in small values of $x$ and evaluating the integral numerically suggests the limit converges to $\frac{\zeta(2)}{4}=\frac{\pi^2}{24},$ but I have no idea how to confirm this analytically, nor does Wolfram Mathematica. A u-substition of $v=xu$ eliminates the dependence of the upper bound on $x$:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{1}{x^3}\int_{0}^1 \frac{v^2}{{(e^{v/x}-e^{-v/x})}^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}dv,$$
but I have not gotten much further than this. Attempts to use L'Hôpital's rule were fruitless. Perhaps a contour integral could help? Not sure.
Even if the exact value of the limit cannot be determined, I would be happy with a proof that the limit does in fact converge.
For context, the preceding integral appeared in the context of statistical mechanics, specifically in determining the vibrational heat capacity of a molecule at low temperatures (see Pathria, Beale exercise 7.32).
EDIT: I only meant to consider the limit from the right in this question, as the two-sided limit does not exist. See SparkleSimp0229's answer for details.

Some comments. Write $$
\int_0^{1/(2x)} {\frac{{u^2 }}{{(e^u  - e^{ - u} )^2 }}\frac{{{\rm d}u}}{{\sqrt {1 - x^2 u^2 } }}}  + \int_{1/(2x)}^{1/x} {\frac{{u^2 }}{{(e^u  - e^{ - u} )^2 }}\frac{{{\rm d}u}}{{\sqrt {1 - x^2 u^2 } }}} .
$$ By the DCT, the first integral tends to $$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{u^2}{(e^u-e^{-u})^2}\mathrm{d}u
= \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{u^2 e^{2u}}{(e^{2u}-1)^2}\mathrm{d}u
= \frac{1}{8} \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{t^2e^t}{(e^t-1)^2}\mathrm{d}t
$$ which you can evaluate via $(25.5.2)$. Try showing that the second integral tends to $0$.

To show the second integral tends to $0$, I think you can substitute $v=xu$ to obtain
$$\frac{1}{x^3}\int_{1/2}^1 \operatorname{csch}^2(v/x) \frac{v^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}dv$$
and then split this integral up from $1/2$ to $3/4$ and from $3/4$ to $1$. On the first interval, $\frac{v^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$ is bounded and the integral $\int_{1/2}^{3/4} \operatorname{csch}^2(v/x)dv$ tends to $0$ faster than $x^3$, and on the second, $\operatorname{csch}^2(v/x)$ is bounded and this upper bound tends to $0$ faster than $x^3$.

In fact, the limit does not exist, because the left limit is not equal to the right limit. However, we can still compute the left and right limit individually.
Let $I_x$ be the integral. Assume that we can straightwaway substitute $x=0^+$,
$$I_{0^+}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^2}{(e^u-e^{-u})^2}\mathrm{d}u=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2u}u^2}{(e^{2u}-1)^2}\mathrm{d}u,$$
and let $u=w/2 \Longrightarrow du/dw=1/2$,
$$I_{0^+}=\frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^ww^2}{(e^w-1)^2}\mathrm{d}w=\frac{1}{4\Gamma(3)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^ww^2}{(e^w-1)^2}\mathrm{d}w.$$
According to the equation 25.5.2 in the Digital Library of Mathematical Functions,
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s+1)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^xx^s}{(e^x-1)^2}\mathrm{d}x,$$
we can know that
$$I_{0^+}=\frac{1}{4}\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{24}.$$
As such, the right limit exists. Besides that, calculating the left limit $I_{0^-}$ would be quite simple with the aid of the right limit. Let $u=-t \Longrightarrow du/dt=-1$,
$$I_{0^-}=\int_{0}^{-\infty}\frac{u^2}{(e^u-e^{-u})^2}\mathrm{d}u=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2}{(e^t-e^{-t})^2}\mathrm{d}t=-I_{0^+}=-\frac{\pi^2}{24}.$$
Thus, the left limit also exist. However, ultimately, the limit does not converge.

Ah, I meant to only consider the right-sided limit in my question, apologies! This answers my question in any case, thank you very much!

@LanceLampert In case if you need a more rigorous proof, you may refer to some of the comments made by other users at the top :)

Thank you! One of those commenters was me, actually, haha.
